# Was the 50 reputation limit for commenting removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've just answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14902018/799558) in SO and was surprised when I saw a comment to the question from a 1 rep user.

was the 50 reputation limit removed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they left an answer that was automatically converted into a comment. The system does this with short answers that simply point somewhere else on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 didn't know that. sorry for the duplicate.